# supertest .expect(function(res) {}) what to return if test is ok

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, mocha.js, supertest

if have a test made with mocha and supertest:

```
describe('GET /v1/news/5339a146d46d35ebe953030a --test', function(){
it('respond with json', function(done){
    request(app)
        .get('/v1/news/5339a146d46d35ebe953030a')
        .set('Accept', 'application/*')
        .set('DEV-ROLE', 'test')
        .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
        .send(json)
        .expect(200)
        .expect(function(res) {
            //THIS FUNCTION RESULT IN A TIMEOUT IF NO ERROR IS THROWN
            if(!('item' in res.body)) throw  new Error("missing item key");
        })
        .end(function(err, res){
            if (err) return done(err);
            done()

        });

    })
})
```

i want to test the resulting body, but i always run in a timeout.
if an error occures, i can throw an error, thats fine. But if no error occures, i run into a timeout if I retourn nothing like discribed in the documentation:

> Pass a custom assertion function. It'll be given the response object
>   to check. If the response is ok, it should return falsy, most commonly
>   by not returning anything. If the check fails, throw an error or
>   return a truthy value like a string that'll be turned into an error

Example im docu:

```
  request(app)
    .get('/')
    .expect(hasPreviousAndNextKeys)
    .end(done);

  function hasPreviousAndNextKeys(res) {
    if (!('next' in res.body)) return "missing next key";
    if (!('prev' in res.body)) throw new Error("missing prev key");
  }
```

I use version 0.12.1

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Waiting for Version 0.13.0 solved the issue. Now it works.